# L'hopital's rule doesn't work

Tags: limits

To compare growth rates of $\sqrt{\log{(n)}}$ and $n^a$,$a = 10^{-4}$, I computed the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\log{(n)}}}{n^a}$. Using L'Hôpital's rule, this limit came out to be $0$. However, it seems obvious that $\sqrt{\log{(n)}}$  grows at a faster rate than $n^a$, is my application of LH rule incorrect?

Comment: "obvious" is, maybe, most dangerous word in mathematics - can you add your proof to question, why and how log "has a faster growth"?

Comment: Maybe you're fooled by what happens for small $n$ ("small" is context-dependent). It can be shown any positive power of $n$ eventually outgrows $\log n$.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you say it is "obvious" that $\sqrt{\log n}$ grows faster than $n^{0.0001}$?

If I choose $n = e^{10^6}$, what are the resulting values of $\sqrt{\log n}$ and $n^{0.0001}$?  Which is larger?

Answer (score 2):

L'Hopital rule is right, the limit is zero. The problem is your intutition. Indeeed

$$\log(n)\ll n^{a}\quad \forall\ a > 0$$
i.e. the logarithm grows slower than any positive power of $a$, no matter how small.